# Is it possible/allowed to use an id with a label tag

Tags: html, forms

can I use a label in an html form with and id or a class? Not sure how to interpret the HTML 4.0.1 specs on this matter, and the web is no use with a lot of differing opinions / uses

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, yes, you can use IDs and classes on `<label>` elements. They're styleable through CSS just like any other HTML element.